# List shared between threads: build a new list in a specific thread referencing elements of the shared list?

Tags: multithreading, list

Let's say I have this static list which is shared between different threads:

```
public static List<myClass> fooList = new List<myClass>();
```

Now, I want to access this shared list in a thread to build its own private list, I would like to do the following:

```
List<myClass> newFooList = new List<myClass>();

lock (fooList)
{
   foreach (myClass element in fooList)
   {
    newFooList.Add(element);
   }
}
```

But if I do so, I'm building a new list which is referencing the same elements as the shared list, so if later I access the newFooList without any lock (as it should be) I'm actually accessing the same elements of the shared list, hence violating the lock, right?

So, the solution is to make new elements in newFooList with the same content as the ones in fooList instead of passing the references?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to synchronize access to the list elements and not the list itself. Then go ahead and synchronize access to those elements methods, not the list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, perform a deep copy of the list if you want to avoid having to synchronize on access to the list `myClass` elements between threads.

As far as the terminology violating the lock, it would be better to say missing synchronization of the elements of `myClass`.  The lock on *the* instance of `fooList` makes sense only for that instance.  If access to the instances of `myClass` objects is allowed only through the List then that same lock on `fooList` also guards them as well.  If you did a shallow copy of the List container then you would need `lock (myClass element)` for every instance of the `myClass` objects, totally different locks.  Hence my explanation of missing sychronization.